# Post an array of Objects along with other contents using Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

i would like to post an array of objects along with other kind of formdata.

Something like

```
{
  country: "us",
  province: "ny",
  cities: [{
    name: "hello",
    size: "small"
  }, {
    name: "hi",
    size: "big"
  }]
}
```

How do I do this in retrofit? I only need the part where it is declaring the retrofit client api.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@PUT("user/doStuff")
Observable<Void> doStuff(@Field("country") String country, @Field("province") String province,
/* What do i do with cities here?? */);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this, but depends how server is configured.

```
public class City {
    @SerializedName("city")
    public String city;

    @SerializedName("size")
    public String size;
}

public class ObjectToSend {
    @SerializedName("country")
    public String country;

    @SerializedName("province")
    public String province;

    @SerializedName("cities")
    public List<City> cities;
}


@PUT("user/doStuff")
Observable<Void> doStuff(@Body ObjectToSend object);
```

Comment: This will work. But is there a way to do it generically? Say. Is it possible to pass an JSONObject[] as cities ?

Comment: What do you mean in "generically"? Gson is faster than JsonObject. And if you use retrofit with rxjava, is recommended to use like this, my example. It will work like a charm.

Comment: For example. My "user/doStuff" api will actually accept a different range of objects. Is it possible to have this retrofit thing to also accept a generic type like JSONObject. And then in my application. I can just invoke some method to convert my object into jsonObject and then i can pass them over.

Comment: You can try to convert them to string, idk. Retrofit is more specific object oriented. In the end, entire object that you want to send will become a string.